# How do I connect to my InterBase db on a Windows Server from Delphi XE?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have installed InterBase on a Windows Server 2008, added a database through IBConsole and I'm trying to set up a connection to it from Delphi XE. I've clicked on the DataExplorer tab and right clicked "INTERBASE/Add New Connection". This is where I am having trouble setting it up correctly. Anyone know this stuff?

I'm waaaay out of my comfort zone here but I'm helping some people out and I'm trying to get this to work myself so that I hopefully can fix the problems they are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I think I figured it out. I added the ip to my hosts file and then made the database name *muppetserver:C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MUPPETDB.IB* as well as opening up port 3050 on the server.